# How can you create a polygon in QGIS which covers a certain elevation range?

Tags: qgis, polygon, elevation, contour

I am trying to isolate 3 different elevation ranges in QGIS (200-1200m, 1200-2200m, 2200-3200). I have made contour lines for each elevation but I want to make them into separate polygons so I can present data for each elevation range individually. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to create `polygons from lines` and then using the `difference` tool on them?

Answer (score 4):

You can make polygons of contours directly.

[image]

Then use Extract By Expression with an expression such as:

```
"ELEV_MIN" >= 1420 and "ELEV_MIN" < 1500
```

[image]