# Crop map by color

Tags: qgis, clip, mapping, digitizing

I digitized a map using QGIS. What I have right now is simply the geolocated version of the picture below (including labels, streets, lakes etc.), i.e. the file does not have any layers or attributes.
What I aim to do is to create separate shapefiles/polygons for the green, yellow and red areas displayed in the image below. Thus these should be created based on the respective area's color in the picture.

I'm a total beginner with QGIS and did not find anything on how to do this online.

[image]

Comment: Use contour polygons, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420866/88814

Comment: I should have been clearer. What I have thus far is simply the digitized version of the map, in other words a picture with geo-coordinates. The map does not have any attributes or layers. It's just a picture.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: thank you for the comment, I just edited my question and hopefully it now fits the guidelines.

Comment: So yes - what's the problem with  contour polygons? This should work.

Comment: Does your image include the text labels and underlying background (the green/yellow areas, white "roads", lake etc)? Anyone saying "Just use the 'contour polygons' tool" thinks you have a clean image with just your red/green/yellow stuff.

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like the image displayed above, including the text labels and slightly varying green/yellow/red shades, depending on the underground the respective color is drawn upon. (Of course the original image is much larger)

Comment: Have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419334/88814

Comment: Is that a one or three band raster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [link posted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419334/88814) by @Babel, I was able to solve the problem. Example for the green color:

1. Use "Identify Features" [image: "Identify Features"] button on the input image and click on a number of green areas of the map.
2. While doing so, note the entries in "Band1", "Band2", "Band3". Identify the maximum and minimum values for the respective color after collecting this data for a number of points.
   [image]
3. Then open the "raster calculator" processing algorithm in QGIS
   [image]
4. Use the following code to set the min and max for each band. Note that in my case the bands are called "coverage_geocoded". Further, the input layer / reference layer needs to be chosen.

```
   "coverage_geocoded@1" > 40 and "coverage_geocoded@1" < 105 and 
   "coverage_geocoded@2" >  100 and "coverage_geocoded@2" < 165 and
   "coverage_geocoded@3"  > 50 and "coverage_geocoded@3" < 145
```

[image]

5. Run algorithm. This creates a new layer with value equal to 1 if the respective section of the image is green:

[image]

Note: To find the "correct" min and max values I had to run the algorithm multiple times, while adjusting the values for points that were not correctly classified before.